# No info file for Auctex when installed manually

Tags: auctex

I just installed Auctex manually.

Auctex seems to work but there is no Info 'chapter' when I type `C-h i m auctex`.

There is no .info file in the auctex directory.

So my question is where do I get the file for the integrated documentation an in which directory should I copy the file?

Thank you.

Comment: Does `./autogen.sh` in the AucTeX installation directory do the trick?

Comment: Cannot check it anymore, because installed auctex now with the package manager. Sorry and thank you for your help. How can I close this issue?